# Disjoint set of records from two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to find the disjoint set of records (what would be left on each of the two original dataframes that is not included in the resulting inner join) between two pandas dataframes based on a MultiIndex?

Am I missing something rather obvious or do I have to spend some time implementing this kind of functionality myself?

I attempted to do this by finding the symmetric difference between the set of muliIndex keys of the two dataframes, but this has proved difficult.  I have been struggling to get this to work.  My other option, which seems like it might be a bit easer is to add a dummy column of integers that can act as a different single index that is preserved even after I do the multiIndex merge so I that I can use the python set operators on this de facto single key.

[Note that this is related to but slightly different than this question because this merge is not based on a MultiIndex object, but on the values in columns of the dataframe: [How do I do a SQL style disjoint or set difference on two Pandas DataFrame objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405975/how-do-i-do-a-sql-style-disjoint-or-set-difference-on-two-pandas-dataframe-objec) ]

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach of finding the symmetric difference is the way to go.

```
In [97]: from numpy import random

In [98]: arrays1 = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ....:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]


In [99]: arrays2 = [['bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'], [
   ....: 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three']]


In [100]: tuples1 = zip(*arrays1)

In [101]: tuples2 = zip(*arrays2)

In [102]: index1 = MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=['first', 'second'])

In [103]: index2 = MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=['first', 'second'])

In [104]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(random.randn(8, 2), index=index1)

In [105]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(random.randn(8, 2), index=index2)

In [106]: df1
Out[106]: 
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one     0.613378 -0.400247
baz   one    -3.005834  0.004879
      two     0.066539 -0.289100
      three  -0.020099  0.644226
foo   one    -0.461458 -1.621812
      two     0.286655  0.110588
qux   one     0.363648 -0.271281
      three   1.707787 -1.832602

In [107]: df2
Out[107]: 
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one    -1.010482 -0.023373
baz   one    -0.040335  1.553905
      two    -0.080283 -0.571686
      three  -0.985722 -0.795481
foo   one     0.623122  2.124316
      two    -0.493333 -0.343462
qux   one    -1.346753 -1.343945
      three  -0.053497 -0.382402

In [108]: sym_diff = (df1.index - df2.index).union(df2.index - df1.index)

In [109]: sym_diff
Out[109]: 
MultiIndex
[(u'baz', u'three'), (u'qux', u'three')]
```

I'm not sure why there isn't a symmetric difference method on MultiIndex.

Comment: Ok, that works when I change line 103 to index2 and the last term in line 108 to df1.index.  The only problem is with the MultiIndex and the size of my dataframes it ends up taking almost a minute to calculate the sym_diff.  I think your way looks more elegant, but what I ended up doing was slightly different.  I resent the index before I merged and then merged twice, keeping the index of one frame the first time and the other the second time. Then I dropped the matched rows by index in each of the original columns.  This was more code, but took more like 5 seconds.

Comment: I'll write up my solution a later today in case that's helpful for anyone to see.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, you're right on both accounts.  It's too bad my way was so slow.  Are your indices sorted ahead of time? I wonder if that's taking the most time or if it's the set operations.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same test data as outlined by TomAugspurger

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a test data set
arrays1 = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
arrays2 = [['bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
           ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three']]
tuples1 = zip(*arrays1)
tuples2 = zip(*arrays2)
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples1, names=['first', 'second'])
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples2, names=['first', 'second'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=index2)
```

which yields the following two tables

```
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one    -0.579214  0.261575
      two     0.912683 -0.475463
baz   one    -0.295739 -0.586646
      two     0.031916  0.199812
foo   one    -0.724781 -1.245275
      two    -0.824759  2.270161
qux   one     0.638533  0.537306
      two    -0.988444 -1.076636
```

and

```
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   one    -0.859494  0.214814
baz   one    -0.446976  1.281912
      two    -0.181159  0.574126
      three   0.212799 -1.592317
foo   one    -1.192866  1.544799
      two     1.025816  0.921364
qux   one    -0.927700 -0.516720
      three   0.610065  0.028249
```

then you can get the disjoint dataframe by

```
df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)].append(df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)])
```

resulting in

```
                     0         1
first second                    
bar   two     0.912683 -0.475463
qux   two    -0.988444 -1.076636
baz   three   0.212799 -1.592317
qux   three   0.610065  0.028249
```

Is that what you were asking for?